# How is a real symmetric matrix a limit of symmetric matrices with distinct eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory, symmetric-matrices, hermitian-matrices

In *Linear Algebra, Gilbert Strang, $4$th edition* the theorem **$5$S (section $5.6$)** is the following -

> Every real symmetric *A* can be diagonalized by an orthogonal matrix *Q*.
> Every Hermitian matrix can be diagonalized by a unitary *U*.

In one of the remarks to this theorem it is stated that -

> A is the limit of symmetric matrices with distinct eigenvalues. As the
> limit approaches, the eigenvectors stay perpendicular.

What does this limit of symmetric matrices denote?

Comment: To clarify, are you asking what it means for a matrix to be a limit of symmetric matrices? Do you know what it means to say $A$ is the limit of a sequence $A_n$ of matrices? Could you please clarify your question a little?

Comment: @Theo Bendit you are correct. I want the explanation, with an example, as to what it means to say A is the limit of a sequence of matrices A_n. I know limits just am not familiar with it being used in the context of matrices.  And then put forth a possible sequence of "symmetric matrices with distinct eigenvalues" for which A will be the limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say we have a sequence of $m \times n$ matrices $A_k$. What does it mean to approach a limit of $A$? It means that $\|A_k - A\| \to 0$ in the real numbers. That is, for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists some $N$ such that
$$k \ge N \implies \|A_k - A\| < \varepsilon.$$
Here, $\| \cdot \|$ is a norm on the vector space of $m \times n$ matrices. Which norm specifically? It turns out not to matter, as the vector space is finite-dimensional.

One such norm could be
$$\|A\| = \sup_{\substack{1 \le i \le m \\ 1 \le j \le n}} |(A)_{ij}|,$$
and using this norm we can easily show:

> $A_k \to A$ if and only if $(A_k)_{ij} \to (A)_{ij}$, as $k \to \infty$, for all appropriate $i$ and $j$.

That is, $A_k \to A$ if and only if the entries of $A_k$ converge to the entries of $A$. This is probably the easiest way to think of it.

Now, as it turns out, multiplication by a matrix is a continuous operation (matrix multiplication is just a series of addition and multiplication of matrix entries), so we see that, if $A_k \to A$, then $A_k B \to AB$.

How does this help us? If $A$ is symmetric, then $A$ can be decomposed like so:
$$A = U^\top D U,$$
where $D$ is a diagonal matrix with real entries (specifically, the eigenvalues), and $U$ is an orthogonal matrix. Indeed, any matrix of the form $U^\top D U$ is also symmetric, and the eigenvalues of $U^\top D U$ are the entries of $D$.

Now, if $A$ does not have distinct eigenvalues, then $D$ does not have distinct diagonal entries. But, what we can do is form a sequence of diagonal matrices $D$ with distinct diagonal entries, but whose entries converge to the entries of $D$. For example, suppose your eigenvalues are $\lambda_1, \lambda_1, \lambda_2$, where $\lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2$. That is, your diagonal matrix could look like
$$D = \begin{pmatrix} \lambda_1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \lambda_2\end{pmatrix}.$$
You could then consider:
$$D_k = \begin{pmatrix} \lambda_1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_1 + \frac{1}{k} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \lambda_2\end{pmatrix},$$
and we'd have $D_k \to D$. Further, unless $\lambda_2 - \lambda_1 = \frac{1}{k}$ for some $k$, each $D_k$ would have distinct eigenvalues, and hence the same is true of $U^\top D_k U \to U^\top D U$.

Note the trickiness there of avoiding other eigenvalues. There's also more trickiness when a repeated eigenvalue is repeated more than once (obviously you can't just do $\lambda_1 + \frac{1}{k}$ for each extra $\lambda_1$, as this will no longer involve distinct eigenvalues). This is fiddly, but not difficult to solve. I won't prove it, but hopefully you're convinced that it can be done, just by choosing other null-convergent sequences other than $\frac{1}{k}$.

I hope that helps!

Comment: The above explanation shows that a real symmetric matrix *A*, either with repeated or distinct eigenvalues, can always be shown as a limit of a sequence of symmetric matrices $A_k = U^TD_kU$ with distinct eigenvalues. I hope that's what the statement - *A is the limit of symmetric matrices with distinct eigenvalues* - means. 

If my above understanding is correct, then I just want to know what is the significance of such an approach. A real symmetric matrix (or Hermitian) has unitary eigenvectors, all right. But what is the use of this sequence approach?

Comment: Well, each $U^\top D_k U$ is similar to $D_k$, as $U^\top = U^{-1}$, and the eigenvalues of $D_k$ are the diagonal entries of $D_k$, which are distinct. So, we have constructed a sequence of symmetric matrices with distinct eigenvalues whose limit is $A$. The existence of such a sequence is what the statement "$A$ is the limit of symmetric matrices with distinct eigenvalues" means.

Comment: As for the "use" of this, it's difficult to tell what uses Strang intends in his book without it in front of me. A similar approach, not necessarily involving symmetric matrices, can be used as a short proof of the Cayley Hamilton theorem in complex space, for example.

Comment: a real symmetric matrix *A* having orthogonal eigenvectors has many applications. This added capability to of being able to view $A$ as a limit to the sequence $A_k = U^-1D_kU$; or the $A_k$s and $D_k$s being similar matrices - does it have some utility as well?

Comment: I am certain that it does have some utility, but I am not personally abreast of it! My interest is more in the theoretical side. If you want to delve further into this, I would recommend making a new question. I think you'll get some interesting answers from it!